# oracle two-way hierarchical query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a question about oracle hierarchical query.

Lets say I have relation table for units relating to each other where unit1 is parent and unit2 is child.

ID UNIT1 UNIT2 OTHER COLUMNS

------lots of data--------

Lets assume I am looking at one unit, and now I want full graph/tree abouts its relations with other units.

It is easy to just get the parents ones that are connected to each other and also the child ones:

```
 INSERT INTO search_table
 SELECT id
   FROM  mytable
  START  WITH unit_id1 = 12 (or any random unit id)
CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR unit_id2 = unit_id1
  GROUP BY id;
```

This is for moving up and similar is for moving down. Now what happens is that when for example moving up 1 step, it does not search for that units child units, but only keeps searching for parents. So basically I if parent unit has another child (not the one we are looking) I wont be able to reach it, because the syntax keeps only looking for parents. And later it looks only for children but not these two combined.

Is there a way that for each child or parent unit, I could search for both parents and children?

Comment: Sample data + desired output, please?

Comment: Lets make it easier...imaggine humans. Lets say I have 2 children. And I have two parents (mom and dad) and they have 2 children (me and my son. Now I am looking myself and wanna hierarchically get all my relatives so to say...using connect by once I get my parents and using connect by unit_id1 and unit_id2 switched I get my 2 children. But I dont get my brother/sister. When I use CONNECT by to get my parents, It will ONLY get my parents, their parents etc. I want the query also check my parents children.

Comment: Have you played with Oracle's `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`?

Comment: Not really, would that help? If i am in the middle of the tree? I did see that option in oracle's documentation, but didnt think that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do it with a single query. 
But you can easily do it in two steps :

1. find the older ancestor A of your unit(the one who doesn't have parents)
2. find all the children of A